How does the string become different encoding and then decoding, and how can I edit my code so it isn't different?
I am working on a javascript code to heavily encode strings.


function splitIntoChunks(str, chunkSize) {
  let chunks = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += chunkSize) {
    let chunk = str.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
  }
  return chunks;
}

function baseLog(x, y) {
  return Math.log(y) / Math.log(x);
}

function stringToNumber(string, bool) {
  var str = string;
  let num = BigInt(0);
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    num = num * BigInt(1103871) + BigInt(str.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  if (bool) {
    console.log(string);
    console.log(numberToString(num, false));
  }
  return num;
}

function numberToString(number, bool) {
  let str = '';
  var num = number;
  while (num > 0) {
    let charCode = Number(num % BigInt(1103871));
    str = String.fromCharCode(charCode) + str;
    num = num / BigInt(1103871);
  }
  if (bool) {
    console.log(number);
    console.log(stringToNumber(str, false));
  }
  return str;
}

function encode(string) {
  var encodedString = encodeURIComponent(string);
  var array = encodedString.split("");
  var newNumberArray = [];
  array.forEach(char => {
    newNumberArray.push(JSON.stringify(10 + char.charCodeAt(0)));
  })
  return encodeURIComponent(numberToString(BigInt(parseInt(newNumberArray.join(""))), true));
}

function decode(string) {
  var weirdUnicodeCharacters = decodeURIComponent(string);
  var jumbledArray = splitIntoChunks(stringToNumber(weirdUnicodeCharacters, true).toString(), 2);
  var resultString = "";
  jumbledArray.forEach(num => {
    resultString = resultString + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(num) - 10);
  })
  return resultString;
}

/* Usage:
encode(str);
decode(str);
*/

// Testing: 
console.log(encode("Hello world!"));
console.log(decode(encode("Hello world!")));



For some reason, the string is being distorted, maybe due to a round-off error or a bug in javascript. I have looked through my code, and I can't seem to find an error. I even added some debugging using console.log. It may be due to the fact I am using BigInt and normal numbers. I am new to javascript and StackOverflow, so some of my code isn't that efficient. Thanks so much!

heavily encode... what does that mean!? String is distorted? What does THAT mean? Sounds like a malfunctioning translation.

There are other problems, but BigInt(parseInt(...)) is clearly wrong. parseInt() can't parse the long integers you're creating. Just use BigInt(...)

You never use baseLog(), why is it in the code snippet?

To which I understand (and it's not much) but ᄘ雷㙠ꃣỲ꺌 it means Thunderstorm in simplified chinese. So my bet is that the questions is translated from simplified chinese to english and does not make sense at all. But from what I can tell is that the OP tries to byte-wise encode text and byte-wise decode text when internally it is UTF-16 or something similar that is incompatible.

Barmar, I am sorry about that. I have edited the code once more, but the error still remains. I had included baseLog because I though I might have needed that when decoding a string, specifically in the numberToString function.

Sani, I mean I want to encode a string in a way where less people would be able to decode it. By distort, I mean when encoding the string but decoding it back, the string is very different, and the string is sometimes blank. The Chinese you are referring to is just some random unicode letters that the code generates when encoding.
